# java.lang.SecurityException on search contact

Tags: java, android

I have an error on my crash report in Google Play, I am searching for a contact in the contact list, in order to know if I have to create it or if it already exists, but it is giving me java.lang.SecurityException on Android 7.0 devices.

This is my code:

```
public boolean contactExists() {
    // Here, thisActivity is the current activity
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RegisterActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(RegisterActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

            showMessageOKCancel("Necesitas permisos para guardar nuestro contácto en tu teléfono y poder enviarnos mensajes");
            return false;

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

            if (Bellisima_number != null) {
                Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(Bellisima_number));
                String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
                Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri, mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
                try {
                    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (cur != null)
                        cur.close();
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}// contactExists
```

I have the contact permission in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
```

I am searching but I can't understand this error.

This is my trace in Google Play

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 



at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1683)

  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1636)

  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider (ActivityManagerNative.java:4263)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider (ActivityThread.java:5475)

  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContextImpl.java:2239)

  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider (ContentResolver.java:1515)

  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:514)

  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:472)

  at co.bellisima.bellisimaco.RegisterActivity.contactExists (RegisterActivity.java:318)

  at co.bellisima.bellisimaco.RegisterActivity.createUser (RegisterActivity.java:209)

  at co.bellisima.bellisimaco.RegisterActivity$1.onComplete (RegisterActivity.java:149)

  at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzc$1.run (Unknown Source)

  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6123)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:867)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post the entire Java stack trace. Also, be sure that you have [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) set up, as `READ_CONTACTS` and `WRITE_CONTACTS` are both `dangerous` permissions.

Comment: Just to be clear... there is nothing after the `:` in that first line (`java.lang.SecurityException:`), and the next thing is the `at android.os.Parcel.readException`? Usually, a `SecurityException` provides more details on exactly what went wrong.

Comment: yes, i just copy and paste just like it is

Comment: If runtime permissions are set up, and you are not able to reproduce the problem, my guess is that it is something specific to the device that had the crash. Perhaps the user revoked a runtime permission, and your code is not expecting that. Perhaps the user has tinkered with your app or with the device in a way that resulted in this crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestPermissions()` is asynchronous. When it returns, the user has not even been *asked* about permissions, let alone granted any to your app.

You need to arrange to do your contact lookup at two points:

- If you already have permission at the time you call `contactExists()` (`checkSelfPermission()` returns `PERMISSION_GRANTED`), you can go ahead and do your lookup
- If you do not have permission, you need to wait until after `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is called and you confirm that you now have the permission